# Xamarin Forms ListView Binding to Child Object List in an Observable collection

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

Please forgive this if the answer is obvious.. I am fairly new to Xamarin and Forms, but not to programing or C#.
I have a ListView that works and binds just fine to the top level object and its immediate properties. It is an ObservableCollection of GameDTOModel Objects.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<GameDTOModel> ActiveGamesCollection { get; } = new ObservableCollection<GameDTOModel>();
```

The GameDTOModel is like this:

```cs
public class GameDTOModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Which Game type is used in this game
    public GameType GameType { get; set; }    
}
```

The GameType looks like this:

```cs
public class GameType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Prize> Prizes { get; set; }
}
```

and the Prize object is like this:

```cs
public class Prize
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}
```

So far so simple and as I said. I have no issue getting to the objects in the ActiveGamesCollection and have bound it to a ListView.
I would like to be able to show the images in the ImageURL property of the Prize object. So for example, a game may have a GameType that has 3 prizes, hence it is a list.
My XAML looks like this:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="GamesView" ItemSelected="GamesViewItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding ...stuff...}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding ...stuff...}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding ...stuff...}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding ...stuff...}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="Loaded "/>
    <Label Text="{Binding ActiveGamesCollection.Count}"/>
    <Label Text="  games from the server @ "/>
    <Label Text="{Binding DebugmsgServerURL}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

The Itemsource and other stuff is set up in the code behind:

```cs
GamesView.ItemsSource = gamesmodel.ActiveGamesCollection;
GamesView.SelectedItem = gamesmodel.SelectedGame;
GamesView.IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true;
```

I do have a copy of the ActiveGames in a List object too but need the observable collection in order to populate the ListView. (it seems).

I would like to be able to list the 3 images in the ListView but am struggling to bind to ActiveGamesCollection.GameType.Prizes since it is and observable collection.
Also I see from reading around that you shouldn't have a listview nested inside a listview, so I need a solution for that too. I guess I could use a gridview, but just getting to them at all would be a start.

Any pointers anyone?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an undefined number of prizes for each game, or it's always 3 items?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have made that clear... A GameType  can have min 1 to max 'undefined' - defined by common sense - prizes.

Comment: {Binding GameType.Prizes[0].ImageUrl} will get you the path to the image, but you have to hardcode the index, so it's difficult to do a layout for an undetermined number of prizes

Comment: Yes, I realise...

Comment: You can try to create your own view that should able to receive that list (`{Binding GameType.Prizes}`) and render it as you wish, basically like what the [RepeaterView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CustomControls.RepeaterView/) does. Maybe it's the way to go. I have no experience with this component yet, so I can't share an answer for now, but I'll research about it.

Comment: Yes... I'll give that a go and maybe just view the first 3 or 4 prizes if there..  thanks for the idea..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **DynamicWrapLayout** inside your ViewCell to show up the images.

```
<suave:DynamicWrapLayout ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <suave:DynamicWrapLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="180">
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </suave:DynamicWrapLayout.ItemTemplate>
</suave:DynamicWrapLayout>
```

> Reference https://github.com/SuavePirate/DynamicWrapLayout